# joomla phoca gallery - exporting from j1.5 and importing into j3+

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla1.5, photo-gallery

I have an old Joomla 1.5 site with Phoca Gallery installed. There are a TON of pictures on this site. I am upgrading the site to Joomla 3+. I have a development site set up where i am building the newer upgraded site.

Is there an easy way to export all of my Phoca Gallery images/categories from the j1.5 site and import it into the newer site?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think, the best method is to upgrade step by step.

First, update from 1.5 to 2.5, see this guide:
http://www.phoca.cz/documents/50-phoca/566-how-to-migrate-extensions-from-joomla-15-to-joomla-25

and then update from 2.5 to 3:
http://www.phoca.cz/documents/50-phoca/831-how-to-migrate-extensions-from-joomla-2-5-to-joomla-3

EDIT:

in short, you need to:

- export data from database (old Joomla! instance, e.g. with help of
  phpMyAdmin)
- backup all needed files of component (images, etc., e.g. with help of FTP), see the guide for information about specific folders to
  backup
- install Phoca Gallery on new Joomla! site (database will be created)
- import the old database tables to new database
- copy the files you made backup to new site

This "short" description is really a short description and you need to read the guides exactly.